# IEEE requirments for images

Tags: image, dpi, journal, ieee

According to http://www.ieee.org/documents/graphicsfaq.pdf The minimum resolution required for images are 300dpi or 600dpi , and i have a large problem understanding this , because they have an online checker tool (http://graphicsqc.ieee.org/) that checks if your image passes the 300 DPI by submitting your image .

My question is How Do they know that my image is 300 dpi just from resolution and not from its size in the paper !? lets say they assume that the image will be presented in its full size so i re sized image in Adobe flash(only tool available right now) and exported it in 300DPI format which re-sized my image from 512X512 to 2133X2133 and then i submitted this image which still failed! so i took the 2133X2133 IMAGE AND RE-SIZED BACK TO 512 AND SAME RESULTS!!

How exactly i know DPI of image and its lower than 300 DPI how to increase its DPI , i thought i increase its DPI by decreasing its size but that also didn't work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DPI value is stored in the image as meta data. How you change it depends in the software that you use. In Gimp, for example, You can change it by Settings the *X resolution* and *Y resolution* in the "Image" -> "Scale Image" dialog.

Comment: That's why if i re size image small or large he still detects the 72 DPI value , so how can i change that value ?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by *re size*. There are two sizes for computer images, the one in centimeters and the one in pixel. The relation between these two sizes is determined by the DPI. How you change it depends on the software that you use. My answer explains how to do it in Gimp, I don't know about any other software.

Comment: You already answered my question I went to image scale in gimp and changed it to 600 DPI and it was done :) , thank you